# Custom styled checkbox (Material Chips) for android studio

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox, material-components-android, android-chips

I would like to create chips in android like shown below:

[image: CheckBox style]

Is it possible to do so with android studio?
If so, how can I do it with XML?

Tried creating this CheckBox but want to know how to add theme like the above screenshot:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
  android:text="Gold" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.113" 
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" 
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code.

Comment: I have just made a default checklist. '<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Gold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.113"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />'

Comment: I want to know how to design it as per the picture. Thanks

Comment: Put this code in the question.

Comment: These are called Chips not CheckBoxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view components you refer to are called [chips](https://material.io/components/chips/).
By using the material design library, you can use chips like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

Source: https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/

In order to use the material design library, you need to:

1. Add the dependency to your app module's gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

2. Use AppCompatActivity
3. Use one of the material desing themes as your parent theme in the app. E.g. `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`

Check out the full getting-started guide [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/).

Comment: When I use this component, it asks me to change my app layout theme to material components. Once I do that, it messes up my entire application button's color and position

Comment: Please tell me what to do

Comment: @LubnaA.Shakoor You can first try out if the birdge themes work. They shouldn't mess up to much: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/#bridge-themes

If not, then you'll have to fix your layouts by hand so that they work with the material theme.